# How to define const int in .h file properly?

Tags: c++, header

In a project, I need to define a const int, I define it in a header as:

```
 extern const int a;
```

And I include that header many times. Then in only one source file, I put:

```
const int a=10;
```

However when I need to use a in an array bound; i.e.:

```
int anarray[a];
```

I get:

```
"array bound is not an integer constant"
```

error. Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An array bound has to be an *integral constant-expression*. To be an *integral constant-expression* an expression must only involve (amongst a few other things) literals, `enum` values and `const` variables or `static` data members **only if they are initialized with *constant-expressions***.

`const` variables of integer type are not *integral constant-expressions* if they don't have a initializer.

It's a language rule that allows implementation to know certain constant values at compile time without having to know about other translation units (which may not be compiled at the same time and which may be changed independently).

`const` variables at namespace scope have internal linkage by default (i.e. without an explicit `extern`) so you won't have any multiple definition problems if you do something like this.

```
// header.h
const int a = 10;
```

.

```
// source.cpp
int anarray[a];
```

Answer (score 5):

The array dimension needs to be known at compile time. For constants such as this you might want to consider using an enum instead. That way its value is visible in the header and you still get the symbolic name when debugging (unlike using a #define).

```
// foo.h

enum {
    a = 10; // array dimension
};
```

and

```
// foo.c

#include "foo.h"

int anarray[a];
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what advantage `enum { a = 10; };` has over `const int a = 10;`. Can you expand?

Comment: @Charles: you can't reliably put `const int a = 10;` in a .h file - some compilers let you get away with it, others not.

Comment: @Paul R: Ermm, I can. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Charles: if the header is #included in more than one .cpp file, then you may get link errors - it depends on the compiler/linker and for some compilers it may well work at -O3 and not at -O0.

Comment: Again, why would you get linker errors? You shouldn't (unless the compiler/linker is defective in some way).

Comment: @Charles: my bad - it's a problem with C, but not with C++. Of course if you share headers with both C and C++ code then it's still a potential problem.

Comment: @Paul R: Yes, in C constant expressions are even more restrictive than in C++. You can't use something like `const int a = 10;` as an array bound.

Comment: @Charles: C99 allows it, and gcc has supported it as an extension prior to C99. But yes, if you need strict C89 compatibility then you are correct.

Comment: @Paul R: I didn't think that C99 treated `const int` as constant integer expression or allows them as array bounds (for non-VL arrays)? (C99 does have VLAs but then you can use even non-`const` values to size these.)

Comment: @Charles: for both gcc (-std=gnu89) and C99 you can use const int as an array size, but only for local arrays. Global arrays still have the same limitations as in C89.

Comment: @Paul R: That's what I understood, but that's really just because C99 has VLAs, not anything to do with `const` or constant expressions.

Answer (score 2):

The value of a constant needs to be known at compile-time. `extern` variables are not so: if at all, their values can only be determined at link-time, which comes *after* the compilation step. So as far as the compiler is concerned, an `extern` is *not* a constant.